# Preservation of compactness under equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact metric space under a certain metric $d_1$.

Let $d_2$ be a metric equivalent to $d_1$. Is it true that $(X,d_2)$ is a compact metric space?

If so how do I go about proving it?

Comment: Compactness is a property of the topology. Equivalent metrics generate the same topology.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true, since asserting that  the metrics are equivalent means that the topologies are the same.